# Macro to delete all columns not in list gets "Type mismatch"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Yet another Question,

I want to `delete` all columns `not` in myList

I get type mismatch I am pretty sure this is the problem `AllHeaders = Array(1, UBound(headname, 2))` I am not making a proper array of the header names

Thanks

Edit: UpDated with
The proper AllHeaders array `AllHeaders = Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value`
Still deletes every thing my logic in the `For` and `If` is screwy

```
Sub DeleteColsNotInList()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim myList As Variant
Dim AllHeaders As Variant
Dim hName As Variant
Dim headname
Dim Destination As Range
Dim iCol As Range


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Select

myList = Array("user id", "user name")   'My list of header names to keep

headname = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Value
AllHeaders = Headers = Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value  'Collect all header names into an array

For Each hName In myList
    For Each iCol In AllHeaders
        If iCol <> hName Then
           iCol.Delete
        End If
    Next hName
Next iCol
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to run the loop **backwards**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub colKiller()
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    For i = nLastColumn To nFirstColumn Step -1
        v = Cells(1, i).Value
        If v = "user id" Or v = "user name" Then
        Else
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary thank you for the code it works great. Also for my edification can you tell me (if its is even worthwhile) what my attempt needs to work

Comment: @Tim The main problem is that **iCol** is an array of values and not an array of columns